# Why is v-model inside a component inside a v-for (using a computed list) changing weirdly when the list changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a computed list to display several forms for changing comments in a database. (backend Symfony / api requests via axios, but unrelated)

The form for the comments itself is in a Vue component.
The computed list is based on a list that gets loaded (and set as data property) when the page is mounted which is then filtered by an input search box in the computed property.

Now when i type different things in the input box and the comment component gets updated the v-model and labels are messing up.

I've tested in several browsers and the behaviour is the same in the major browsers.

I've also searched the docs and haven't found a solution.

Example to reproduce behaviour:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="app"></app>
</html>
```

```
const ChangeCommentForm = {
    name: 'ChangeCommentForm',
    props: ['comment', 'id'],
    data() {
        return {
            c: this.comment,
            disabled: false
        };
    },
    template: `
<form>
  <div>{{ comment }}</div>
  <input :disabled="disabled" type="text" v-model="c">
  <button type="submit" @click.prevent="changeComment">
    Change my comment
  </button>
</form>
`,
    methods: {
        changeComment() {
            this.disabled = true;
            // do the actual api request (should be unrelated)
            // await api.changeCommentOfFruit(this.id, this.c),
            // replacing this with a timeout for this example
            window.setTimeout(() => this.disabled = false, 1000);
        }
    }
};

const App = {
    components: {ChangeCommentForm},
    data() {
        return {
            fruits: [
                {id: 1, text: "apple"},
                {id: 2, text: "banana"},
                {id: 3, text: "peach"},
                {id: 4, text: "blueberry"},
                {id: 5, text: "blackberry"},
                {id: 6, text: "mango"},
                {id: 7, text: "watermelon"},
            ],
            search: ''
        }
    },
    computed: {
        fruitsFiltered() {

            if (!this.search || this.search === "")
                return this.fruits;

            const r = [];
            for (const v of this.fruits)
                if (v.text.includes(this.search))
                    r.push(v);
            return r;
        }
    },
    template: `
<div>
  <form><input type="search" v-model="search"></form>
  <div v-for="s in fruitsFiltered">
    <ChangeCommentForm :id="s.id" :comment="s.text"/>
  </div>
</div>
`
};

const vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {App},
    template: '<app/>'
});
```

Just type some letters in the search box
Example on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLLYmq

Now as shown in the example the div in CommentChangeForm gets updated correctly, but the v-model is broken.

I am wondering if i miss something or this is a bug in Vue?

Comment: You didn't add keys. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Comment: Could please be more specific. What data do you type in which field? What is the observed behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: ay, keys where the problem; thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve state of DOM elements between renderings, it's important that `v-for` elements also have a `key` attribute. This key should remain consistent between renderings.

Here it looks like the following might do the trick:

```
<div v-for="s in fruitsFiltered" :key="s.id">
  <ChangeCommentForm :id="s.id" :comment="s.text"/>
</div>
```

See:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key